# Get around tkinters' askopenfilename filetype check

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinters' askopenfilename with a handful of predefined filetypes:

```
tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=self,
                                   title=_("Select Attachment"),
                                   multiple=False,
                                   initialdir=initialdir,
                                   filetypes=filetypes)
```

filetypes include 'png', 'jpg', 'bmp', ...

The filedialog will only show me files of the specified type as I expected.
But when I type in the file name it will just accept it, no matter of which type it is.

Is this a bug of tkinter? Is it expected behavior? Do I need a workaround or can I change askopenfilenames' behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that to be the intended behavior.  After all -- [You can't actually know the file's data type until you open it up](http://xkcd.com/1301/).

So no matter what you do, a user can get around it simply by renaming a file with one of the program's whitelisted extensions.  Of course, if you really want to be robust, you could read the first few bytes and [check the magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) and hope that's correct ;-).

Comment: Of course the user can cheat by renaming it. It's just ugly to have different behavior when the file does not exist (handled from askopenfilename) or when the given filetype is unexpected (handled from my code). The difference is obvious...at the one hand the askopenfilename remains open waiting for a new file name on the other hand the askopenfilename is closed and reopened after an invalid file name.

Comment: I never realized that this is the intended behavior for every file dialog out there.